# Is this moment in High Noon a line flub?

Tags: dialogue, high-noon

Every time I've watched [*High Noon (1952)*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0044706/) I've been somewhat aware of what seems to be awkwardness between Gary Cooper and Grace Kelly in the scene right after they are married. Not sure if this is just a difference in culture over the past 70 years but in any case, there is a moment that especially seemed strange and off to me and I've always wondered if it was a mistake that made it into the final cut.

When everyone is in the main office congratulating Will and Amy, there is a moment where he picks her up and sets her on a desk as she screams and laughs. He then says, "Not til you kiss me!", and after a second or two of laughing Amy says, "Put me down!" Another second or two of awkward laughing after which they kiss and he lets her down.

Shouldn't she have said "let me down" before he says "not til you kiss me"? Was this a flub in the lines? If so, why not get another take with the correct lines?

Comment: It was obvious that she wanted to be put down from her behaviour. He was responding to her struggling. I'm guessing here just wasn't a good take when she said the scripted line first, however, and so they cut it, assuming the audience would get the gist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well according to the [script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/High_Noon-1952-Shooting-script.pdf), Amy says “Will, let me down,” Will responds “Not till you kiss me,” and she then insists “Let me down, you fool!”

[image]

It's pretty clear to me that that's what I'm seeing and hearing in the film, too. But I cannot find any way to link to the scene (at 8:40) because have found no place to watch the movie online free of charge.

Comment: After rewatching this she does actually say "Let me down" twice. Before and after he says "Not till you kiss me." So seems like its not a flub, but I always missed her saying it the first time before.